# Javascript Reverse match process

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking at the RegExp object docs and couldn't find a method that does what I want, or I'm just not looking hard enough.

Say I have text:

```
var text = "§193:And Some Text§";
```

And a RegExp object:

```
var reg = /§([0-9]+):(.*?)§/;
```

Running `reg.match(text);` would obviously give me an array like so:

```
["§193:And Some Text§","193","And Some Text"]
```

Is there a way to sort of reverse this process? Such that I give an array, with the same number of matching groups that the RegExp has, to a function and gives me back what the text would look like:

```
var reg = /§([0-9]+)§(.*?)§/;
var data = ["293","Some New Text"];
var text = reg.rmatch(data);
```

and `text` would now be `§293:Some New Text§`

Am trying to make a plugin system for my code, and a part of it entails getting a regexp from the plugin and using it in several processes, e.g. extracting data, reconstituting original text from some data.

Right now I would have to make the plugin provide a function that would return the original text, and was hoping there was a way of making it so they didn't have to by just reusing the regexp some how. I could prototype a custom function onto the RegExp class and then use that, I was just hoping it already had some process to do this.

Comment: Seems like something for one of the various JavaScript template systems. In general doing this with a regular expression seems weird; for some regular expressions it would be undecidable.

Comment: I've done something like "reverse regex" in php, you might take a [look at it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1401975+%5Bregex%5D+reverse).

Comment: Yea it does seem weird, but the way im using it is that the regex are being used in an web editor to transform like bb code to html and back again. i can already do the to and back again by using the regex to extract the parts needed and then saving the original text on the object using jQuery's data function. This problem comes into play when making new elements in the editor, they dont have the original text because it was never there so needed a way for the editor itself do it.

Comment: No, in general this is impossible. You would need to capture everything that is optional or has alternatives, and not all regexes do that. Better use a custom reverse function, you can easily do that with your bb codes for sure.

Comment: Array[0]? - It usually always contains the full text, that matches.

Comment: In your example, how would it know to put `:` between the values?  As Bergi said, this is generally impossible, given the nature of regex.  You could, however, write a different regex to accomplish what you're looking for.  Or are you looking for a way to replace multiple matches at once? (not exactly the same as reversing a regex)

Comment: @dognose For this question, the fulltext was never available, that's what he's trying to construct from the regex and match parts.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti, the : was supposed to be in the regex it was a typo, what i was looking for was a way to replace each group "()" with a corresponding array element. Like ([0-9]+) is group 0, so it would be replaced with data[0] but looks like ill have to make a regex to match the groups my self and replace. Only problem with that is if there are subgroups etc, or just make the plugin do the work of generating the code which was whati  was trying to avoid

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ok, I understand now - The crux of the issue is that you want to replace each of the parenthesized submatches with the corresponding index in the array.  `replace` can take a function as a parameter to create the replacement substring...  you can probably work with that.  Here's a reference, if you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function rregex(regex, data) {
    var arr = new String(regex).split(/\(.*?\)/);
    if (!(arr instanceof Array) || !(data instanceof Array) ||
        (arr.length != data.length+1)) return false;

    var result = arr[0];
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result += data[i] + arr[i+1]; 
    }
    return result;
}

var reg = /§([0-9]+):(.*?)§/;
var data = ["293","Some New Text"];

console.log(rregex(reg, data))
```

result

```
/§293:Some New Text§/
```

Of course this is fundamentally impossible when regex's features are used outside the capture groups (apparently I have nothing better to do with my life:) Even without regex feature use outside the capture groups: how will you reconstruct a case insensitive match with correct case?

And of course a lot could be done to improve the above code.

Comment: Well so far i havent had the need to use anything outside the capture groups, or subgroups, so replacing the groups with a function like you have is what would "work". Of course it breaks once subgroups etc are used. And as for case, case doesnt matter, for instance img code would be `§img:3§` which would only need /§img:([0-9]+)§/, and `[3]`, a link code `§link:Link Text§http://www.google.com§` needs `/§link:([^§]+)§([^§]+)§/` and `["Link Text","http://www.someurl.com"]`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible if the `regular expression` doesn't match the entire string or fails to match completely.

For example `"abc".match(/.(.)/)` returns `["ab", "b"]` but does not contain the full string anywhere thus losing the last character "c".

But if your regular exprssion works and matches the entire string,For example `"abc".match(/.(.*)/) returns ["abc", "bc"]` Then you can grab the full string via `myResult[0]`

Comment: this is not what is being asked, what is being asked is make 'abc' given only the regular expression, and an array of data that matches the number of capture groups.